# Required field validator still firing even after removing from Model & Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting error regarding required field validator, two field on my razor page & it should not be required. So I removed the `[Required]` validation attribute but still I am getting a message after submit that these fields are required.

Below is my model properties.

```
public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
decimal Latitude { get; set; }
```

& this is razor.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Longitude, new { @class = "form-control")
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Latitude, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: A `decimal` can never be `null` - its must have a value. if you want to allow `null`, then make the nullable

Comment: make both the attributes nullable.

Comment: Yes its working thank you # Stephen Muecke and #Anmol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your Controller:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

It will work fine then.